# java new constructor with array and int

Tags: java, arrays, constructor, compiler-errors

I am practicing with Java, and I'm trying to build an constructor that takes in an **int[] array**, and an **int**.

```
public static App(int[] name, int n) {}
```

Now in my main(), I am trying to build a **new** object with the constructor, and I'm getting an error message.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n;
    int[] name = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    App app1 = new App(name, n);

}
```

The error message I'm getting back is:

"constructor App in class App cannot be applied to given types;
required: no arguments; found: int[],int; 
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length"

Can someone please explain more about what this error means, and how can I correct my code?

Comment: A constructor can't have a static modifier.

Comment: A constructor should (a) have the exact same name as the class (including upper/lower case), (b) no return type, (c) no `static` modifier.

Comment: a constructor cannot have a `return` type and must not be `static` also you dont want it to be `private`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static App(int[] name, int n) {}
```

Thae became a static method with invalid signature and that is not constructor.

According to your description, It should be

```
public App(int[] name, int n) {

}
```

Comment: I have changed from public static to public on the constructor, and I am still getting the same error message.    To be more clear, my constructor now reads ``public int[] app(int[] name, int n) {} ``

Comment: @as.beaulieu It should not be. Atleast a different error message. Can you post a screenshot ?

Comment: @as.beaulieu Why there is a return again ? it should be just `public  App(int[] name, int n) {}`

Comment: @as.beaulieu, what is `app`? Isn't your class named `App`? Please clarify.

Comment: @as.beaulieu it must not have a return type not even `void` please change your constructor to the specified answers

Answer (score 1):

A constructor does not have a `static` modifier, and a static method needs a return type. Your posted code isn't valid.

```
public static App(int[] name, int n) {}
```

should be

```
public App(int[] name, int n) {}
```

As it is, your class doesn't have a constructor at all - so you get the default (no-args) constructor.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code, you need to resolve both of them to make it compiled.

(1) A constructor can't have **`static`** keyword, so remove it

(2) **variable `n` is not initialized**, so initialize it before its first use as shown below:

```
int n=1; //or any value you wanted
```